# Applying query filter like the one in codelab (Cloud Firestore) is not working

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore for my project to store data , my issue is that i can not 
filter data just the way codelab filter does .The result of that query gives me the whole collections docs which means the filter is not working.
I've tried many workarounds and find out that only when I cascade whereEqualto()
methods in one line I get what I want of specific docs , but this approach (cascading whereEqualTo inline) is not flexible when giving the user a way to filter searches.I just want to know why that code is not working for me.

// Does not work

```
Query query = mFirestore.collection("restaurants");

    // Category (equality filter)
    if (filters.hasCategory()) {
        query = query.whereEqualTo("category", filters.getCategory());
    }

    // City (equality filter)
    if (filters.hasCity()) {
        query = query.whereEqualTo("city", filters.getCity());
    }
```

This works:

```
   query.whereEqualTo("realEstateType", realEstateType).whereEqualTo("propertyStatus", propertyStatus).whereEqualTo("propertyPhysicalStatus", propertyPhysicalConditionS).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {



            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: here is a link to cloud  Firestoe codelab   https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ,It seems that I was not assigning to query object the filter as follows:

```
query = query.whereEqualTo("fieldPath" , ...);
```